# What type of damage would be used for an incompatible blood type?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, damage

For my campaign there is an option at higher levels to take a blood transfusion with a half orc half hobgoblin and I want the creature to take damage if they aren't either of those races, what damage type would that be?

Comment: Is your transfusion homebrew content? Also, are you running a published adventure or a completely homebrew one?

Comment: First of all, welcome to the site! Feel free to take the [Tour] if you haven't already. On to your question, why damage specifically? Assuming that blood transfusion is rare in a typical setting, my first instinct is to suggest instead a short-term (as in "no more than 2 sessions of IRL time") debuff or some other form of narrative effect. Damage is just a healing spell.

Comment: This definitely seems to fall under the opinion-based option. I think you could improve it away from that by asking about the balance implications associated with choosing a specific damage type coupled with additional information about your campaign as a whole.

Comment: I second @3C273 in questioning the premise of damage, it is also likely to be at least slightly opinion based so not a great fit for this site. You are best off asking about the implications of a specific type (Pick whichever you currently favour for example), or defining what you aim to achieve with the resource drain and asking if there are any rules which cover that kind of effect.

Comment: why do you think it should do any damage at all? are you trying to simulate blood clotting? if not, why and how the damage occurs? if it is magical (for instance, light vs dark creature), please do include it in your question. These will help making this question less opinion based

Comment: Not seeing how this is opinion based. The OP has damage they want to apply and they want to know what type it is. If you don't think there's support for a definitive answer by RAW then that's your answer.

Comment: @lightcat The question is a homebrew question. It's inherently not raw so that's not really an answer. It's up to OP to either provide a clear description on *why* and *what* is causing this damage to help give better direction to determine type. But right now, it's very idea generation-based to help develop their homebrew.

Comment: I don't see this as opinion based. A blood transfusion is a thing, damage is caused to the body if you use incompatible blood types. Given the available damage types we should be able to formulate a supported argument for why a particular damage type is most suitable for this damage.

Answer (score 0):

## Use rules for poison or disease

All possible damage types in 5e are:

> - Acid
> - Bludgeoning
> - Cold
> - Fire
> - Force
> - Lightning
> - Necrotic
> - Piercing
> - Poison
> - Psychic
> - Radiant
> - Slashing
> - Thunder

The closest thing to the case you're describing is a disease. Diseases normally deal **poison or necrotic damage**. The precise amount depends on how severe this condition is, therefore, is totally up to you as the DM.

You can use poison rules for any suitable poison from DMG as inspiration. An example:

> A creature subjected to this poison must make a DC 10 Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, it takes 6 (1d12) poison damage and is Poisoned for 24 hours.

Comment: @enkryptor then I suggest you include this reasoning in your answer :) Also, some diseases also deal necrotic damage instead of poison, so I don't think necrotic would be too far-fetched.

Comment: And it may be possible to use a non-damage item (like HP-reduction). I think your decision on poison needs some kind of support.

Comment: @DavidCoffron the OP explicitly asked for damage

Comment: I agree that, if answerable, the most likely culprits are Poison or Necrotic - but what's your reasoning on your preference for Poison? You haven't backed up your answer with anything.

Comment: @NautArch there is no preference for Poison

Comment: Well, said (without backing it up) that this seems to closely describe a disease and that diseases usually deal poison or necrotic. But then you jump to Poison as your final answer. So that very much seems like you are preferring Poison over necrotic by that choice.

Comment: @enkryptor The OP asked what damage type would that be, and the answer *might* be: usually these types of effects don't deal damage and instead do [some other effect]